# Add Column with average time difference of rows with same column values

Tags: powerquery

I am given a PowerQuery table like this:

| ID | A | B | C | COUNT | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a1 |  | c1 | 0 | 2017-05-10 09:55:28 |
|  | a3 | b | c2 |  | 2017-05-10 10:12:54 |
| 2 | a2 |  | c3 | 2 | 2017-05-10 10:19:47 |
|  | a2 | b | c4 |  | 2017-05-10 10:20:24 |
|  | a2 | b | c5 |  | 2017-05-10 10:21:50 |
| 3 | a3 |  | c6 | 1 | 2017-05-10 10:31:02 |
|  | a3 | c | c7 |  | 2017-05-10 10:31:02 |

Here, the column `COUNT` checks whether column value `ID` is non-empty and if so it counts the rows with same column value `A` **such that** column value `B` equals "b".

Now, I would like to add a column `AVG_TIME_DIFF` which again checks whether column value `ID` is non-empty and if so:

- checks wether `COUNT` equals 0, in this case returns "0"
- else takes the Timestamps of all rows with same column value `A` **such that** column value `B` equals "b" **as well as the row itself**, orders them (i.e. `COUNT`+1 many rows) chronologically and returns the average time difference in seconds
- else the result is empty

In the example table above, the result should be

```
ID | A  | B | C  | COUNT |      Timestamp      | AVG_TIME_DIFF
 1 | a1 |   | c1 | 0     | 2017-05-10 09:55:28 | 0
   | a3 | b | c2 |       | 2017-05-10 10:12:54 |
 2 | a2 |   | c3 | 2     | 2017-05-10 10:19:47 | 62
   | a2 | b | c4 |       | 2017-05-10 10:20:24 |
   | a2 | b | c5 |       | 2017-05-10 10:21:50 |
 3 | a3 |   | c6 | 1     | 2017-05-10 10:31:02 | 1088
   | a3 | c | c7 |       | 2017-05-10 10:31:02 |
```

Fractions of seconds can be rounded up or off as you wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try below. Note that count column is not needed

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index2", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index", each ([ID] <> null)),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"ID", "A"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Custom",  (x)=>Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index", each [A]=x[A])),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom","AVG_TIME_DIFF2", each
    let
    z= Table.SelectRows([Custom], each [B] =null or [B]="b"),
    a= Table.Sort(z,{{"Timestamp", Order.Ascending}}),
    b=  Table.AddIndexColumn(a, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    c = Table.AddColumn(b, "Custom", each b{[Index]-1}[Timestamp]),
    d = Table.AddColumn(c, "Times", each [Timestamp]-[Custom],type duration),
    e = Table.Skip(d,1),
    f = Duration.TotalSeconds(List.Average(e[Times]))
    in f, type number),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"ID", "A"}),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Custom", {"ID", "A", "B", "C", "COUNT", "Timestamp", "Index2"}, {"ID", "A", "B", "C", "COUNT", "Timestamp", "Index2"}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded Custom",{{"Index2", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "AVG_TIME_DIFF", each if [ID]=null then null else if [AVG_TIME_DIFF2]=null then 0 else [AVG_TIME_DIFF2] ,type number),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"AVG_TIME_DIFF2", "Index2"}),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns1",{{"Timestamp", type datetime}})
in #"Changed Type1"
```

[image]